# Rails query construction without ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Forgive me for being vague, but I was shown this technique by someone and I don't remember what it was called so I've had a hard time searching for it.

With Rails models and ActiveRecord we can of course run all sorts of queries, however, these can consume a lot of resources and become less and less feasible over time.  The method I was shown was a way of essentially building a query as a chain of methods before actually executing the query.

So something like `Users.active.address` would set up the query to look for Users where active=true and where an address is set.  I'm not sure what this is called, or where I can learn more about it.

Comment: Those are called Scopes.You can refer them in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: You are Welcome! And enjoy the Scopes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the privilege of adding my comment as an answer,as no question should go Unanswered in **SO**.

Those are called Scopes.You can refer them in [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/active_record_querying.html#scopes)